# How to get the value from DB based on the user input using Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, knockout.js

I need to get the value from Database based on the user input.
Please find below snapshot of the DB.

[image]

I have dropdown in my frontend which display the (Name) from the database, I need to get the Folder based on the category I select from the frontend.
This is what I have tried in typescript:

```
    loadResourceCategory() {
      this.categories = new Array<ResourceCategory>();
      this.isLoading = true;

      return this.resourceService.getResources()
        .then((categories: Array<ResourceCategory>) => {
          this.categories = categories;
          this.categories.forEach((category: any) => {
            category.details = `${category.Name}`;
            this.selectedCategory = category.Id;

            if (category.Id === this.selectedCategory) {
              this.foldername = category.Folder;
              console.log('Selected Category folder is :', + this.foldername);
            }
          });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.modalService.error('Resources cannot be loaded now, Please retry later');
        })
        .finally(() => {
          this.isLoading = false;
        });
    }
```

Currently I get the ID of the Name i select from the dropdown. I am unable to get the Folder. How can I fix this? Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved!! Just removing "+" resolved this issue.
console.log('Selected Category folder is :', + this.foldername);